# Recently when I updated my application and App is rejected

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, google-developers-console

Please Help Me Fix this issue.

Recently when I updated my application(OXOO movies streaming app) I receive this email from Play Console:

*Your app contains content that doesn’t comply with the Device and Network Abuse policy. We found your app is using a non-compliant version of an SDK which contains code to download or install applications from unknown sources outside of Google Play.*

*The SDK can be identified using the classname **com.dcastalia.localappupdate.DownloadApk.**
Affected Version(s):
App Bundle:3, App Bundle:3, App Bundle:3*

But I have checked everything but have not found anything like this in the application.

Please give me some advice to fix this.

It is really important for me to release an update.

Answer (score 0):

remove
implementation 'com.github.Piashsarker:AndroidAppUpdateLibrary:1.0.3'
from your build.gradle